# Laravel BelongsToMany how to retrieve model values based on conditions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Now I have 3 tables

shirt

```
id type
```

color

```
id color
```

color_shirt

```
id color_id shirt_id
```

Shirt model

```
    public function colors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Color');
}
```

Shirt controller

```
 public function show($color)
    {
        $color = Shirt::find('round_collar')->color();
    }
```

It will return all colors of round_collar shirt, what if I want to return a specific color?

It doesn't work in the following way:

```
$color = Shirt::find('round_collar')->colors()->where('color','=','red');
```

When I refer to the document http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many , it doesn't seem to have examples. Anybody knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a ->get() or ->first() at the end, like this:

```
$color = Shirt::find('round_collar')->color()->where('color','=','red')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but it returns `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'color' in where clause is ambiguous`

Comment: try $color = Shirt::find('round_collar')->colors()->where('color','=','red')->get(); you are calling color() method, and you have colors() method in model.

Comment: right,I drop the s in this question but actually it will be undefined method if it's due to such fault.thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Eager Loading Constraints' (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

```
Shirt::find('round_collar')->with(array('colors' => function($query) {
    $query->where('color', '=', 'red');
}))->first();
```

As a sidenote, I'm doubting you want to use find('round_collar') in that way. You probably want where('collar', '=', 'round') instead.